# Windows search using file version field

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-search

I need to find file `name.dll` which has version number `1.1.1` in `Windows 8`.
Is it possible to make search according fields `FIle version` and `Product version`?

Comment: Is it a requirement to limit yourself to the built-in search? If not, this sounds like something that you could hack in PowerShell.

Comment: @elderelder I'd hardly call it a "Hack" in PowerShell. I'm pretty sure it's a standard property of file objects that support it.

Comment: You are 100% spot-on. Poor choice of words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Advanced queries like this aren't really supported in general-purpose search tools like you'd find built-in to Explorer or the Charms Bar. However, PowerShell (which also comes built-in to Windows 7 and later) is very much capable of handling the task.

In PowerShell, file objects have a property called `VersionInfo` which contains child properties that have the data you're looking to filter by. Once you know how to reference these properties, building a script to search for files based on them is fairly trivial.

For all files named "name.dll" with a File Version of "1.1.1" on C:\, do this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Include name.dll -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion -eq '1.1.1'}
```

For all files named "name.dll" with a Product Version of "1.1.1" on C:\, do this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Include name.dll -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -eq '1.1.1'}
```

For files named "name.dll" which have a File Version OR ProductVersion of "1.1.1" on C:\, do this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Include name.dll -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.VersionInfo.FileVersion -eq '1.1.1' -or $_.VersionInfo.ProductVersion -eq '1.1.1'}
```

Bear in mind that these will only match if the values of File Version or Product Version are *exactly* equal to the string "1.1.1". For information on how to use these commands in other ways, including the ability to match based on other criteria or using Regular Expressions, you should check some of the built-in help documentation with the following commands:

```
Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Detailed
Get-Help Where-Object -Detailed
Get-Help about_Comparison_Operators
Get-Help about_Operators
Get-Help about_Regular_Expressions
```

Comment: Got error. $.ProductVersion : The term '$.ProductVersion' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program.

Comment: @user1501700 Sorry. I was writing that post off the top of my head from my phone. I forgot an underscore, and after some further testing it seems even that's not quite enough. Give me a minute to work out the proper syntax.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an 'old' post but it is possible to search for a file by file version in windows search.

Open an explorer window to the base directory from where you want to search, for example, C:\windows. 
In the search box type in [fileName].[ext] AND system.fileversion: <= 1.1.1.1 (or whatever version requirements you have).

You can use wildcards in combination with the BOOLEAN operators for the search parameters. See the following Microsoft site for some suggestions. Note that the list provided is not a complete list so I had to sort of guess to figure out I can search for 'System.fileversion'
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/advanced-tips-for-searching-in-windows

Here is an example I did from a folder on a network resource:

```
system.filename:~=AmazingCharts AND system.filename:~>exe AND system.fileversion:~=6.7.0
```

- The first parameter searches for all files that contain the words
  'AmazingCharts' somewhere in the filename value.
- The second parameter isolates the search for all files that END in exe
- The third parameter further filters the search results to those values that
  contain 6.7.0.

I did notice that search results are slow for this process.